# What are the best comic books to get introduced to Top Cow Witchblade/Artifact series?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, top-cow-universe

I would like to start getting into [**Top Cow**](http://www.topcow.com/) comics' **[Witchblade](http://www.thetopcowstore.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1)/[Artifact](http://www.thetopcowstore.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=3) series.**

**What would be a good approach to start reading these series?**

***My only familiarity with that universe is:***

- The TV series "Witchblade", which I assume was done based on the comics.
- Some random facts discovered on [comicvine](http://www.comicvine.com) database when I was researching answers for previous [top-cow-universe](/questions/tagged/top-cow-universe) questions.

***Some tactics I can think of are:***

1. Should I merely start with the [oldest comics on Top Cow](http://www.thetopcowstore.com/SearchResults.asp?searching=Y&sort=4&cat=12&show=200&page=1)?

   These seem to be "Angelus Volume 1", "Witchblade: Prevailing", "Magdalena Origins Volume 1" and some others that didn't seem Witchblade/Artifact related.

   However it's hard for me to tell if any given title belongs to Witchblade/Artifact line or not.
2. Should I start with specific Witchblade series comics?
3. Should I start with some "best of" set? If so, which?
4. Should I start with specific issues containing critical info, even if they are not oldest or best? If so, which?
5. Your other idea.

***Notes/details:***

- I explicitly cenetered on Witchblade/Artifacts series, but if any tied-in series issue (Magdalena?, Angelus?) should be included in the starter set, I'm fine with that.
- I am open to the idea of reading the comics in order other than #1=>#N in the series, provided most of the significant plot info from the ones I miss can be found online, such as ComicVine
- If possible, the recommendation should fit into [4 waves of 3 issues](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/970/976)
- If possible, the recommendation should be biased towards comics available for sale, especially at comixology. Howeever, that is a weak preference - I'd rather expend the effort tracking down a hard-to-buy issue if that issue is considered critical to read.
- For any suggestions, it would be strongly appreciated if specific reasoning to choose that specific set/order is provided instead of simply a bare list.

Answer (score -2):

There is a good summary on reddit of the various stories and runs. I personally reckon grabbing both compendiums will set you on your way. That way you have the first 100. https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/6bfss7/the_witchblade_reading_guide_what_to_read_and/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The link you refer to may be useful, but this answer by itself could use some work.  You should include details from the linked resource so that it's clear what it says, and so the answer stands on its own.  You might want to check out [answer].  Also, the question specifically requests "it would be strongly appreciated if specific reasoning to choose that specific set/order is provided."